# PHP object mapping unexpected

Tags: php

I'm working with ebay API, trying to get some transaction history data.
When I do my request to API it returns the following:

```
print_r($soldlist);
///
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [OrderTransaction] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Transaction] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Buyer] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                  ...
            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Transaction] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [Buyer] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                  ...
.....
```

So I'm only interested in an OrderTransaction so i can put it inside array_map function like this:

```
array_map(function($order){....}, $soldlist->OrderTransaction);
```

Buy php comes up with warning:

> Message:  array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array

So I did `print_r($soldlist->OrderTransaction)` and insted of returning an array it returns the first element of it:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Transaction] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Buyer] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (....
```

How do i return an array to use it with map?

**EDIT:**
It is interesting that if I do straight iteration it works like this:

```
foreach($soldlist->OrderTransaction as $order){...}
```

Comment: `array_map(function($order){....}, (array)$soldlist->OrderTransaction);` maybe you can cast it to an array.  `SimpleXMLElement ` is more like a resource wrapper, and so it can produce some "weird" behaviour.

Comment: I tried print_r(((array)$soldlist->OrderTransaction)); and it still returns the first element only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_map` explicitly requires an array as the second parameter... The xml element is not an array but an object with a [traversable interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php).

Meaning you can use `foreach` on these elements but not `array_map`.

Note that you can cast the element to an array as suggested in the comments. However, you may loose some of the objects information while casting. So Foreach is the the better answer.